# what is [object Byte[]] in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, arraybuffer

My program has a variable "photo", when it calls Object.prototype.toString.call(photo), it shows [object Byte[]].
What is this type? How do I create an array with the same Byte[] type?

Comment: it is the byte array of the image data

Comment: do you know how to create a similar one from an arraybuffer? I read a file from <input> in HTML5 and want to convert the input file to this data exactly.

Comment: client side javascript or server side ?

Comment: Where are you getting `photo` from?

Comment: It is at client side. The file in open in <input> tag and read as arraybuffer.